# Windows 10 People app encoding for Vcards

Tags: windows, character-encoding, outlook, uwp, vcf-vcard

We got a complaint that our Vcards were not correctly encoded for the new Windows 10 Phone OS (which uses the People app as its contact storage).

Currently we supply Windows agents Vcards with an `ISO-8859-1` encoding, which works for Outlook, but doesn't seem to work as well with this new People app. I tried using `UTF-8` encoding instead, and the opposite occurred, that is it worked perfectly with the People app but then stopped working with the Outlook client.

Is there some way/encoding that will work with both platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up having to fish up the platform from the user agent:

```
if 'Windows Phone' in user_agent:

    return 'UTF-8'

if 'Windows' in user_agent:

    return 'ISO-8859-1'
```

Not really the elegant solution I was hoping for so certainly post a better answer if you have it.